# How to find out why \cite works on one computer while not on another computer when the same local files are present?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, ieeetran

I am using the IEEE class and `.bst` style templates for `.tex` and `.bib` files. One my laptop the citations come out as question marks. At the university the `\cite{}` get compiled correctly. I have locally the files for the `.cls` and `.bst` files although I expect the packages between my laptop and university to be different (`IEEEtran.bst` / `IEEEtran.cls`).

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
\title{Simulating...}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{yoyo and yoyo}
\IEEEauthorblockA{blah\\
University ...\\
Mars\\
Email: ???}}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
blah
\end{abstract}
%\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
\section{Introduction}
intro
\cite{WS}
Here we simulate...
\section{Conclusion}
The conclusion goes here.
\section*{Acknowledgment}
The authors would like to thank...
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,mrefsAlex}
\end{document}
```

How should I go about checking what dependencies are missing on my laptop because no errors are given.

Comment: And do you process your document using `pdflatex+bibtex+pdflatex+pdflatex` to generate the citations?

Comment: Look at your `.log` file.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the command `\listfiles` to you document. That will print a list of all loaded files in the LOG. so you can compere the version installed on your laptop and at the university.

Fro example that code

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
File check
\end{document}
```

gives the following short list.

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 ***********
```

Comment: +1.  But it doesn't have to be before the documentclass declaration.

Comment: @jon: Thanks I corrected it. I thought it won’t see the document class files if it’s after it …